# TreeView Access: как добавить иконки?

Tags: access, vba

Не могу сделать, чтобы вместо стандартных обозначений в `TreeView` (крестик) были созданы иконки папок для родительских веток и другую картинку для детей.
Не понимаю, как заполнять `ImageList`, чтобы потом его можно было выбрать в свойствах (`properties`)? 
И какие должны быть свойства картинки (будущей иконки)?

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

вынесено из комментариев.

---

Нашел ответ! Добавил в форму *ImageListCtrl* через панель инструментов, дальше залил через нее иконки (получилось только формат *ico* 32x32), а дальше в прописании ветки указал индекс, который автоматически появляется в *ImageListCtrl*.

Answer (score -1):

Не помню уже толком детали, но помню, что сначала надо создать список изображения в виде отдельного компонента. Его можно было заполнять либо через свойства, либо программно.

Потом у самого дерева надо выбрать имя списка изображений в каком-то из свойство компонента TreeView. И ещё надо выбрать Style во что-то типа picuture + text, иначе всегда будут отображаться знаки плюс-минус.

К сожалению, больше деталей не помню.

Comment: К сожалению, я тоже знаю в общем как делать, а нужны детали, потому что возникают проблемы

Comment: Нашел ответ!
Добавил в форму ImageListCtrl через панель инструментов, дальше залил через нее иконки (получилось только формат ico 32x32), а дальше в прописании ветки указал индекс, который автоматически появляется в ImageListCtrl.